How to Select the Best Periods of PPG Signal?
I'm training a deep learning model on PPG signals and need to select the best (clearest) periods of PPG from each subject's data. Initially, after preprocessing, I selected 10 periods with the highest and lowest peaks, as shown in the image, to train my model. However, I want to enhance my results by refining my period selection method so that the chosen periods are more feature-rich. For example, they should include both systolic and diastolic peaks, as some noisy recordings lack these features in all periods.


In the attached recordings, the selected periods using my previous method are highlighted on the preprocessed signal (right-hand side) in different colors. In the first image, this method works well because the recording is relatively noise-free. However, in the second image, there are better periods with more relevant features that could be used for training, even though they don’t necessarily have the highest or lowest peaks.
How can I select the best 10 periods that are most representative of a clear PPG signal from the recordings? Would it be a good idea to use correlation as a metric? If so, what reference signal should I use to calculate the correlation, considering that the best periods for each subject may not be determined by a single reference signal?
Thanks in advance for your help!

This is a very specific problem you’re asking a solution for. Answering this will benefit you and you only, and would require quite a lengthy knowledge sharing session, or a lot of work on our part to come up with a solution.
I suggest you google “signal quality index for PPG signals”.
There are some good references that deal with this. At the end of the day though, you’ll need to adapt to your data.
From what I see in your screenshots, you probably would need an algorithm to first segment each beat, then detect fiducial points such as dicrotic notch, systolic peak, etc, for each beat, then compute time and amplitude metrics based on those. For example, $\frac{\texttt{systolic amplitude}}{\texttt{dicrotic notch amplitude}}$, or $\frac{\tt{beat length}}{\tt{systolic time}}$, etc
You can then use these ratios to compute your quality index: if they are outside a range you define, discard them. You could also weigh them favorably/defavorably based on their “quality score”.
Good luck!
